# Importing Mysql statements into Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, database-design

I'm new to using Laravel.

I have a .sql file where created a whole bunch of tables("CREATE TABLE my_table......."). Is there a way to somehow import these statements into Laravel? I could always manually rewrite these tables in raw php, but I feel that this would take too long and there is possibly an easier way to do it.

Comment: Laravel is getting in your way?  What advantage is it?

Comment: I think you need you need to study "Laravel Query Builder" https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries. And for that "MYSQL Statements" you mean, there are few statements that can be still accessible in Laravel with the use of "selectRaw or DB::raw" see: [1]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55384313/whereraw-laravel-with-variable/55386020?noredirect=1#comment97494239_55386020 [2]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319163/how-to-perform-trim-and-concat-in-laravel-query-builder . How will help you..

Answer (score 0):

You would use migrations in Laravel to do this for example

I want to create a table called tasks I would use this command in artisan

```
php artisan make:model Task
```

This would create a model called task and a migration for this table.

You can then access the migration file and input something like this

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTasksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('task_id');
            $table->string('name');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('tasks');
    }

}
```

You would then run the artisan command to create this table

```
php artisan migrate
```

This then automatically creates your table.

Its a very useful feature and you can also rollback your migrations or even refesh it meaning it will remove the table and then reinstate it with no data in.

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

link to the docs
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations