# How to perform TRIM() and CONCAT() in Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I tried to take FirstName, middlename, Lastname used the Query Builder in combination with RAW but failed. is my way wrong? Thanks

```html
$student = \DB::table('student')
                        ->select(DB::raw('RTRIM(LTRIM(CONCAT(
                                          COALESCE(FirstName +  ''),
                                        COALESCE(MiddleName +  ''),
                                        COALESCE(Lastname, ''))))
                                        AS Name'))
                        ->get();
```

Comment: `COALESCE(FirstName +  '')` doesn't appear valid

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Eloquent models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$student = DB::table('student')
    ->select(
        DB::raw("TRIM(CONCAT(FirstName,' ',MiddleName,' ',LastName)) AS Name")
    )->get();
```

**TRIM** Function - Remove leading and trailing spaces from a string [See examples and how to use it](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_trim.asp)

**CONCAT** Function - Add several strings together using *comma*: [See examples and how to use it](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp)

Hope will help you :)

Answer (score 3):

Why not using Laravel model way of achiving this?

```
class Student extends Model {

     protected $appends = 'full_name';

     public function getFullNameAttribute() {
         return $this->FirstName . ' ' . $this->MiddleName . ' ' . $this->LastName; 
     }
}
```

Then, `Student::get()` will have `full_name` attribute for each student.

Comment: Well, you could use Eloquent for this, but they aren't.  So I'm not sure it's really an answer to use an ORM over the query builder.

Comment: @Devon It's a perfectly good answer barring an "I can't use Eloquent for <good reason>" from OP.

Answer (score 1):

The `+` symbols should be a comma:

```
$student = \DB::table('student')
    ->selectRaw("TRIM(CONCAT(COALESCE(FirstName,  ''), COALESCE(MiddleName,  ''), COALESCE(Lastname, ''))) AS Name")
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$student = \DB::table('student')
               ->select(\DB::raw('CONCAT_WS(" ", `FirstName`, `MiddleName`, `Lastname`) as Name'))
               ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$student = Student::select(\DB::raw('CONCAT_WS(" ", `FirstName`, `MiddleName`, `Lastname`) as Name'))
               ->get();
```