# How to use SQL TRIM Function in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm working on a school project that register and login with "username", as far as i tested i can't find any good method to work, I've found this function of SQL TRIM which removes spaces and other character if anyone knows how to work with it in laravel.

reference:
http://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-string-functions/sql-trim/

Comment: Is there any problem with using php trim function?

Comment: you try here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319163/how-to-perform-trim-and-concat-in-laravel-query-builder

Comment: that solved my problem thanks! @JGEscarilla

Comment: got it solved
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319163/how-to-perform-trim-and-concat-in-laravel-query-builder

Comment: glad it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this Example:

```
$data = DB::table('table_name')
->select(
  DB::raw("TRIM(CONCAT(field1,' ',field2,' ',field3)) AS Name")
)->get();
```