# WhereRaw Laravel with variable

Tags: laravel, postgresql, query-builder

I'm trying to do this query but I got an error (Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded):

```
DB::table('my_table')->select(DB::raw("id"))
    ->whereRaw('UPPER(name)','=', $upper_name)
    ->pluck('id')->first();
```

I'm trying to add the `UPPER` sql function to the query. With direct sql, the query should be:

```
select * from my_table
where UPPER(name) = 'HELLO'
```

Where `$upper_name` = HELLO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simpliest Way to do that. Hope will help you

```
DB::table('my_table')->select('id')
    ->where(DB::raw("UCASE(name)"), $upper_name) 
    ->first();
```

[UCASE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ucase.asp) - Convert the text to upper-case

Comment: Thanks, much better. I'm in PostgreSQL, but that where with DB:raw is better.

Answer (score 0):

Bah... I got it:

```
DB::table('my_table')->select(DB::raw("id"))
    ->whereRaw('UPPER(name) = ?', $upper_name)
    ->pluck('id')->first();
```

Comment: Yeah, `whereRaw` you can do the whole statement on a string or bind it like you did

```->whereRaw('UPPER(name) = ?', $upper_name)```
or
```->whereRaw("UPPER(name) = $upper_name")```